# In Akka (Java), how can I have my Supervisors log any exceptions caught?

Tags: akka

The Akka documentation explains how to log from within an actor (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/logging.html). But how can I log from within a supervisor?

I basically want to log any exceptions that are caught by the supervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer, and realised my question was maybe not right. I needed the SupervisorStrategy to actually log the exception. When I create my supervisor UntypedActor it can define a SupervisorStrategy which should be able to access the (final) Logger of the enclosing UntypedActor.